# Deleting item in tableView at rowindexpath removes the item below it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a strange issue. I have a populated tableview that allows users to delete items by swiping right and tapping "delete". The functionality works just fine, successfully deleting the item from the table as well as from the data source (a Drupal node). However, for some reason, when I swipe an item to delete it, it actually deletes the item UNDERNEATH of the one I'm selecting in my data source. **E.g.** I choose to delete node 133 in my tableview, and node 132 is what gets removed.

I've created a string that grabs the node id of the selected row from Drupal, but it's almost as if it's grabbing the node id prior to the one in my selected row...

**See code:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.descripData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];
        NSString *nid = [nodeData objectForKey:@"nid"];
        [nodeData setObject:nid forKey:@"nid"];
        [DIOSNode nodeDelete:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"node deleted!");
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"could not delete node!");
       }];

        [tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you grab the nodeData *after* you delete the data from `self.descripData`. So in affect you do grab the next row's data. Reverse the order.

Also, don't call `reloadData`. You already remove the deleted row from the table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.descripData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        NSString *nid = [nodeData objectForKey:@"nid"];
        [nodeData setObject:nid forKey:@"nid"];
        [DIOSNode nodeDelete:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"node deleted!");
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"could not delete node!");
       }];
    }
}
```